# Help in jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have form elements like this:

```
<input type='text' id='person_1_name'>
<input type='text' id='person_2_name'>
<input type='text' id='person_3_name'>
<input type='text' id='person_4_name'>
<input type='text' id='person_5_name'>
..
..
..
```

I can select single element like this:

```
$("#person_1_name").focusout( function() {

   alert("Hello World");

});
```

Is there any selector that select all elements(person_<*>_name) like this without describing them separately ?

Thanks

Comment: Woudn't it be simpler to wrap them in an element and then acces them like this: $('wrapperelement input').focosout(function() { /**/ }); ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**this is not the right way .**

you should add Class to each of the elements and then select it by :

```
$(".MyClass")...
```

but if you insist :

```
  $('div') .filter(function() { return this.id.match(/person\_[0-9]\_name/); }) .css('border','solid 1px red')
```

Comment: +1. You can use filters on the ID value, but I'd rather avoid it where possible.

Answer (score 3):

JQuery emulated CSS selectors. So, this should work well:

```
$('input[id^="person_"][id$="_name"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

[`$("id[id^='person_']"); //starts with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)
[`$("id[id$='_name']"); //ends with`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the person_n_name elements and use a class selector instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could try by picking them with a class. First set them a class and then pick them via script

like this:

```
<input type='text' id='person_1_name' class='person'> 
<input type='text' id='person_2_name' class='person'> 
<input type='text' id='person_3_name' class='person'> 
<input type='text' id='person_4_name' class='person'> 
<input type='text' id='person_5_name' class='person'> 

<script type="text/javascript">

var person = $(".person");
```

person var will contain a array

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to add `class='person_name'` in your `input` and use

```
$(".person_name")focusout( function() {

   alert("Hello World");

});
```

But if you are forced to use `id` then you can use the code below

```
$("input[id^='person_'][id$='_name']").focusout( function() {

   alert("Hello World");

});
```

See a working demo here http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/aPD5K/

Answer (score 0):

This should work (untested)

```
$('input[id*="person"]')
```